# Test case with enum requires key after upgrade Rails from v4 to v5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums, rspec

I am in the process of upgrading my Rails app from v4 to v5. When I run the tests, some of them fail which used to pass before.

For instance,

(enum)

```
enum session_type: {regular: 0, demo: 1, promotional: 2}
```

(usage)

```
session = {
          :uuid => SecureRandom.uuid,
          :session_type => 0,
}

post :create, :format => :json, params: { :session => session }
```

The parameter goes through a `params.require(:session).permit(...)`

```
'0' is not a valid session_type
/home/anz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/enum.rb:137:in `assert_valid_value'
/home/anz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:67:in `with_value_from_user'
/home/anz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:51:in `write_from_user'
/home/anz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:50:in `write_attribute_with_type_cast'
/home/anz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:32:in `write_attribute'
/home/anz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:20:in `__temp__3756373796f6e6f547970756='
```

When I use `regular` instead of `0`, it works. What's going on?

---

**UPDATE 1**:

Doing so correctly parses the parameters

```
@request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'
post :create, :format => :json, params: { :session => session }
```

I tried `as: :json`, but it failed to work. I wonder why it is not working, looks way better than adding `@request.env`.

```
post :create, as: :json, params: { :session => session }
```

---

**UPDATE 2**:
After updating rails from 5.0.0 to 5.0.7.2, `as: :json` is working.

```
post :create, as: :json, params: { :session => session }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at the error message, it is complaining about `'0'`, not `0`.

If you try to set `session_type` to a string, then it is expecting `'regular'`, `'demo'`, or `'promotional'`. If you use a number then it expects `0`, `1`, or `2`. But ActiveRecord isn't clever enough to try converting a string to a number before seeing if you're passing a valid value so it just sees `'0'` is something that isn't in `%w[regular demo promotional]` and tells you that you're passing an invalid value.

So either fix up the clients to send in strings or adjust your argument parsing to map strings to numbers with something like this:

```
def model_params
  permitted = params.require(:session).permit(...)
  if(permitted[:session_type].in?(Model.session_types.values.map(&:to_s))
    permitted[:session_type] = permitted[:session_type].to_i
  end
  permitted
end
```

Comment: ```request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'
post :create, :format => :json, params: { :session => session }``` seems to be preserving all non-string values. Doing each wasn't so effective, as I have more than 10 field whose values got converted to string.

Comment: JSON knows the difference between strings and numbers so if you're sending in JSON you should have something like `{"session_type":0}` which gives you `permitted[:session_type] == 0`. But plain CGI parameters from a form only know about strings so you'd get `permitted[:session_type] == '0'` there. Hence the test against `Model.session_types.values.map(&:to_s)` to pick out just the values that have to be converted.